# Cannot download composer - 1and1 with ssh access to server

Tags: php, composer-php

I have SSH access to my 1and1 server. I am trying to download composer.

Following instructions from http://getcomposer.org/download/

Attempt 1:

```
user:~ > curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in <b>-</b> on line <b>316</b><br />
```

Attempt 2:

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>] 
       php <file> [args...]
  -a               Run interactively
  -b <address:port>|<port> Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode
  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse <file>.  Implies `-q'
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -q               Quiet-mode.  Suppress HTTP Header output.
  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

I know that it is saying that I am running php 4.4.9, but if I run phpinfo(), it says `PHP Version 5.4.21` is running. Any suggestions on what is going on here?

**phpinfo()**
[image: phpinfo()]

**php -v**
[image: php -v]

Comment: od you run recent PHP?

Comment: Thats the strange thing... If I run phpinfo, I get `PHP Version 5.4.21`

Comment: What does `php -v` gives you?

Comment: PHP 5.4.21 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Oct 18 2013 08:45:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

Comment: I'm wondering where the `X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9` is coming from. Because when I inspect the headers of https://getcomposer.org/installer it isn't there..

Comment: Try downloading the file first, after that install using `php -f ./installer`

Comment: @Koen it is coming from remote server `curl` is talking now to

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski is it? Because `curl -I https://getcomposer.org/installer` doesn't return such header.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Currently 1&1 offers a bunch of PHP versions under different aliases.

However the easiest way to set a default PHP version to use is from your 1&1 dashboard PHP settings and set it per domain individually. This is located under Hosting and then PHP settings. [[1&1 PHP Settings (United States site)](https://account.1and1.com/ExtPhpSettingsOverview)]

Note that 1and1 updates the PHP versions now quite regularly and also the CLI version may differ to the one user to render your site.

**Original answer.** It's been a long time, I recommend using the the latest 7.x.
There actually are 4 versions of php preinstalled on all the 1and1 linux shared hosting.

Command:

- `php`: Version 4.4 (The one you're actually using with composer.)
- `php5`: Version 5.2
- `php5.5`: Version 5.5
- `php6`: Version 5.4

You have to invoke composer using php5.5 and it will just work.

Comment: Great answer. Be aware though that I was running PHP 5.5.25 but it was `php5` that worked for me.

Comment: Saved me tons of headaches !

Answer (score 5):

You should use the correct version of PHP  `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php5.5`

Answer (score 1):

On 1and1, the PHP version for your virtual server seems to be frozen until you update it.  There's a "global PHP version" page on the dashboard.  I just found it and advanced mine from 4-something to 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting different php versions is because 1and1 has different php versions installed, for both client, and web.

So, if you change your settings (in the 1and1 control panel) so that you're using php5.4, when you run the phpinfo() command, it will reflect that.

However, the command line version will still reflect the default php version for 1and1, which is 4.4.9 (as of today).

So, force the php5 version for your composer install, but also change the global version to 5.4, and you'll be fine.

Here's what happened when I did it.

```
~/demo > curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.28  
Content-type: text/html

#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /homepages/19/[my1and1info]/htdocs/demo/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
(uiserver):[my1and1info]:~/demo>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that server is your production server, you probably shouldn't use it to complete your application, but use your local development machine to download everything, and then upload the whole directory.

From what I see on your shell, you are using a PHP version that is ancient. It is the PHP 4.4 version used as command line, and this clearly does not work with composer. Either you search for the 5.3 version of PHP on that machine (I wonder if it might be called `php53` or something), and then hope all necessary extensions are installed, most likely including the "GIT" command line tool, probably also "SVN", or that search will not really help you, because you still would lack the necessary tools for a successful Composer experience.

Composer is a development dependency manager. It probably is not intended to maintain a production server's code base.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. Composer is a development dependency manager, however I use `composer update` in development, and `composer install in production`. I remove `composer.lock` from the `.gitignore`. That way, when I push to bitbucket/github, then pull into production, I run `composer install` to download and install the package dependencies as per my `composer.lock` file.

Comment: I have not used FTP for deployment in years. I always use git & composer.