# Installing composer on GoDaddy hosting cause parse error

Tags: installation, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on my shared Godaddy's hosting. I need composer to install laravel.
I'm using PUTTY to connect via SSH.
I do connection successfully,
when type

```
-bash-3.2$ ls
```

I get these folders:

```
 data  html  scctmp  tmp
```

Then I type this:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

it return me:

```
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_NEW in <b>-</b> on line <b>382</b><br />
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the php version being outdated (at least php-cli). I guess that's common when you're in a shared hosting.

Type `php -v` and make sure the version  is greater than 5.3.2, which is the older version you can get to install Composer for package management.

Comment: php -v get me `PHP 4.4.9 `
I have to say that user's php version and webserver version are almost the same, user's is `PHP 4.4.9` and web server's is `5.4.19`. I have readed this title, but nothing helps. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734097/cannot-download-composer-1and1-with-ssh-access-to-server)

Comment: So that's the problem :). You have v4.4.9 in cli, so composer will not work for you. As said before, you need 5.3.2

Comment: I could switch php version of the web server to 5.3 in cPanel, if I do so, may I run `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` in php file with web request?

Comment: Composer is a cli tool, so no. You need to change the cli version to 5.3.2+. As you're in a shared hosting, you can't do that. Your only alternative is to change the hosting plan :)

Comment: OMG, I've just noticed that my version is **4**.4 not **5**.5, buy buy godaddy, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if still needed, but worked for me when using

```
-bash-3.2$  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /usr/local/php5_3/bin/php
```

and

```
-bash-3.2$ /usr/local/php5_3/bin/php composer.phar install
```

which is invoking PHP 5.3.14.

Answer (score 4):

on shared hosting such as 1and1 or GoDaddy try:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php5.5
```

or

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php5
```